# C#: How to send/receive a string to a specific IP address in local network

Tags: c#, string, network-programming, ip

I want to make a programm that works like an instant messenger and I´m already finished but I don´t know how to send/receive strings to a specific IP adress.

I included myself a Method where this stuff belongs to:

```
//is called every second and when you commit a message
public void Update(ref eStatus prgmStatus, ref eProfile userProfile)
{
    UpdateUI(ref prgmStatus);
    [ Some other Update Methods ]
    [ Catch the string and add it to userProfile.CurrentChatHistory]
}

public void EnterText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _usrProfile.CurrentChatHistory.Add(chatBox.Text);
    [ send chatBox.Text to IP 192.168.0.10 (e.g.) ]
}
```

I want to use a client to client System without any extra server software running.

What system namespaces and methods can I use to achieve this?

Comment: 1st Result on Google : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C

Comment: There are plenty of networking tutorials for C# on the Internet.

Comment: It´s not that useful because my program is a client to client messenger, without any server

Comment: In this case each client must be also a server.

Comment: ...which is usually problematic in most scenarios because firewall must be opened, routers configured to forward ports (or if you're very daring, configured by uPnP) etc. There's no magic bullet here. You need to **learn** how to do this. Nobody here is going to write this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.Net namespace is where you will need to look.

If you are doing a peer-to-peer chat where you may need to send messages to multiple IP addresses, with no central server, it may be best to use UDP.

Having seen from your comment that you have no central server, I'd suggest you use UDP, at least initially, for a quick start up. The [UdpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is your friend here, allows you to send packets to any specified network address.

You can basically just create a new UdpClient instance, passing a known port number to bind to into the constructor.

Then, use the Receive method to read a packet on that port.

You can also then use the Send method on the same instance to send a packet to a network address.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this for another question a while back. If you'd like to use the async/await features of .Net4.5, here's a simple echoserver that should get you started:

```
void Main()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,6666);
    try
    {
        listener.Start();
        AcceptClientsAsync(listener, cts.Token);
        Thread.Sleep(60000); //block here to hold open the server
    }
    finally
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        listener.Stop();
    }

    cts.Cancel();
}

async Task AcceptClientsAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken ct)
{
    while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        EchoAsync(client, ct);
    }

}
async Task EchoAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var buf = new byte[4096];
    var stream = client.GetStream();
    while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, ct);
        if(amountRead == 0) break; //end of stream.
        await stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, amountRead, ct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems really complicated... I don´t understand this snippet -.-

Comment: That´s the reason why I ask and my Application is complete except of the Network part because I don´t get it o.O

Comment: OK, but you *really* don't get it. As such your question really qualifies as "overly-broad" and should be closed.

Comment: It seems that the Async part is complicated, that's why he said that.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a client/server architecture using the [System.Net.Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class.

The server can be a third computer or one of the chatter. If you choose the second option the first person who start a chat must run a listening socket on a specific port and the second must connect to it using the IP adress and the port.